What would be the most efficient way to encode a simple fraction on 32 or 64 bits?
What would be the best way to encode a positive simple fraction on 32 bits or 64 bits?
For casual binary fraction, we already have a well defined standard for floats and doubles.
In case of 32 bits, one of ideas would be to simply assign 16 bits to the numerator and 16 for denominator. However this approach has two flaws:

it doesn't scale as well as float (as float automatically scales up well by increasing the exponent)  - that's the lesser issue
much bigger issue is that simple fractions may repeat themselves in this case (for example 1/2 is same as 2/4) which may unnecessarily waste the memory. Technically we could use encoding method like we just assign a number to each irreducible fraction like:
1/1 -> 0, 1/2 -> 1, 2/1 -> 2, 1/3 -> 3, 3/1 -> 4, 2/3 -> 5, 3/2 -> 6

and so on but then I can't think of any algorithm that would reverse this process (to retrieve the numerator and denominator) in reasonably short time.

Do you have any ideas?

Is it an option to define your new encoding to be only useable for reduced fractions? I.e. make the weakness a feature. It is possble to store the value of 2/10, but if retrieved, it is correct by definition to return 1/5. I ask because I suspect a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem If this is not an option please elaborate on what you want to achieve with your new encoding.

yes but this will create holes in the encoding - for example encoding itsself will allow for 4/8 but it will never be used - so we get same memory issue

Interesting question, maybe also for https://math.stackexchange.com! In any case, you write "efficient", but what do you mean? Do you want to optimize for memory usage, CPU or something else? That said, I don't understand your encoding method from the examples given.

I do ont think so, it has not more memory issue than the first approach, but it avoids the vastly reduced upper limits, is hence still able to store more values.

I just want to store common fractions in memory - they are used to approximate real values. While I don't read them often (so the readin algorithm doesn't need to be fast, it should still be somewhat efficient at least. Some nice balance between memory efficiency and speed - for example 16 - 16 bit approach is very fast for read/write but very memory inefficient

Oh, one more thing: Is there any other constraint on the values than that they are positive? Like e.g. a range?

@UlrichEckhardt I assume you refer to the code-formatted example. I consider it a "I thought of ... but rejected it." and is not really something that needs to be understood. (Though I think I got it....).

No there is no constraint, i jsut want to be able to encode as many values as possible - and just like floats - the smaller numbers, the more exact representation possible

So - just want to have a standard like float - but for common fractions isntead of binary ones

@Eckhardt - my encoding method would firstly use natural numbers up to 1, create all possible irreducable fractions, then up to 2, repeat the process, then up to 3 and again repeat the process..

Such algorithm would be reversable but without smart algorithm it would be prohibitevely long to reverse it (especially on 64 bit)

Here's one approach which may not be perfect but perhaps it could be a starting point: If you have a fraction and split both numerator and denominator into their prime factors, an irreducible fraction will only have each prime either as part of the numerator or denominator. If a prime is in both, it could be reduced. Further, you can replace the n / d way of writing fraction with n * d^-1, same goes for the form using prime factors.
Now, in consequence, it means that you can write the n / d fraction like this:
n / d = p1^e1 * p2^e2 * p3^e3 * ...

The numbers px are the primes (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19...), i.e. predefined and unchanging constants. The exponents ex are the powers these primes have in the fraction, varying with the value of the fraction.
Bitwise Representation
For practical purposes of a bitwise representation, you could split you target bits into several fields. E.g. you could split 32 bits into 8 fields of 4 bit each. Those four bits would represent the exponents ex for the first 8 prime numbers. The range of the exponents would be limited to -8..7.
The advantage is that you only have one representation for a fraction, so you can do a bitwise comparison to check for equality. In other words, the problem with treating 1/3 the same as 2/6 doesn't occur.
The downside is that you have a limited range and precision, similar to floating point numbers. Since the exponent range is capped to e.g. 7, then you can't represent the value 256 exactly. Further, since the primes are capped, too, you can't represent any prime outside precisely either. For the example above using 8 primes, the 9th prime (which is 23) can't be represented exactly. Depending on your use cases, this may or may not be a show-stopper, I'd at least expect some confusion from this "weird" behaviour.
Summary
I think that this is mathematically interesting. However, I don't think this is efficient use of both your time and other resources (CPU in particular). I have a feeling that this overcomplicates things and cause more problems than it would solve in the end.

Looks like we got simillar ideas :)

In this one we would have issues to write even a number like 23 (as it is a 9th prime number, we would lose the exactness too soon)

We could encode fractions (i.e. rational numbers) using the corresponding continued fraction. Every positive rational number has a correspondence with two finite (simple) continued fractions, where the longer of the two has one more value which is always one.
Example
For example, the fraction 415/93 has four numbers in its shortest continued fraction: [4; 2, 6, 7]. It represents this formula:
               1
 4 + ───────────────────
                1
       2 + ───────────
                 1
             6 + ─
                 7

This representation can be derived by extracting the integer part of the fraction, and then inverting the resulting fraction, to repeat the process until 0 is left. The so generated numbers are all non-zero, except possibly for the very first one.
The same fraction can also be encoded with the longer continued fraction, where the final 7 is replaced with 6 and a 1 is added: [4; 2, 6, 6, 1]. It is trivial to see that this represents the same number.
Encoding continued fractions
To encode a continued fraction in an int you could use run-length encoding, such that each number in the continued fraction is represented by as many bits with the same value (either all 0 or all 1), and alternate the value for encoding the next number in the continued fraction. For this we should choose the odd-length continued fraction (to ensure that the most significant bits of the encoding are always a group of 1-bits). For the example above, the odd-length continued fraction is [4; 2, 6, 6, 1], and the encoding into binary bits would be done starting at the least significant bits:
1000000111111001111
││     │     │ └── 4
││     │     └──── 2
││     └────────── 6
│└──────────────── 6
└───────────────── 1

Decoding
It should be clear how you can decode the binary representation: taking the lengths of the distinct bit-groups, one can get the numbers of the continued fraction 4, 2, 6, 6, 1, and then it is a matter of calculating the numerator and denominator from that continued fraction.
Negative fractions
To add support for negative fractions, you would just reserve a sign bit in the binary representation.
Limitations
Obviously, the number of fractions that can be encoded that way will be limited by your int size, and it may not at all be intuitive why a certain fraction cannot be encoded in it, while another can: it depends on the sum of the numbers in the continued fractions for them.
Secondly, there is processing time needed for the encoding and decoding, which makes this less interesting in time critical contexts.
Implementation as demo
Here is an implementation in plain JavaScript -- just as a demo. As you change one of the inputs (numerator, denominator, encoding), the other values are adapted by either encoding or decoding. This implementation supports unsigned numbers only:


function toContinuedFraction(num, den) {
    const terms = [];
    while (den > 0) {
        terms.push(Math.floor(num / den));
        [num, den] = [den, num % den];
    }
    if (terms.length % 2 == 0) {
        terms.push(terms.pop() - 1, 1);
    }
    return terms;
}

function fromContinuedFraction(terms) {
    let den = 0, num = 1;
    for (let i = terms.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        [num, den] = [num * terms[i] + den, num];
    }
    return [num, den];
}

function encode(num, den) {
    const terms = toContinuedFraction(num, den);
    let code = 0;
    for (let i = terms.length - 1; i > 0; i -= 2) {
        code = (((code + 1) << terms[i]) - 1) << terms[i-1];
    }
    return ((code + 1) << terms[0]) - 1;
}

function decode(code) {
    const terms = [];
    let lastBit = 1;
    let count = 0;
    while (code > 0) {
        if ((code & 1) == lastBit) {
            count++;
        } else {
            terms.push(count);
            lastBit ^= 1;
            count = 1;
        }
        code >>= 1;
    }
    if (count || terms.length == 0) terms.push(count);
    return fromContinuedFraction(terms);
}

// I/O handling

const [inpNum, inpDen, inpCode] = document.querySelectorAll("input");

document.addEventListener("input", e => {
    if (e.target === inpCode) { // decode the code into fraction
        [inpNum.value, inpDen.value] = decode(+inpCode.value);
    } else { // encode fraction into code
        inpCode.value = encode(+inpNum.value, +inpDen.value);
    }
});
<table>
<tr><td>Numerator:</td><td><input type="number" value="0" min="0"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Denominator:</td><td><input type="number" value="1" min="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Encoding:</td><td><input type="number" value="0" min="0"></td></tr>
</table>




Also an interesting idea! However as you mentioned, we may encounter an issue where some simple fraction may not be able to be encoded in a 32 bits even though it may look simple. Netherless it is another approach that is still better than naive 16-16 representation

Ok I got one of ideas - technically, every fraction for example 36/16 can have numerator and denominator expressed as a product of prime numbers raised to some power - in this example we have (2^2 * 3^2)/(2^4). However if we divide it, then we can express it as: 2^(-2)*3^2. So every fraction can be expressed as a product of prime numbers raised to some power (can be both positive or negative). if we express fraction in this way then we get rid of the problem of reducable fractions.
So possible encoding could be just writing the index of a prime number and then exponent on the bits.
So firstly i would asasign a number to every prime number like:
2 -> 0, 3 -> 1, 5 -> 2, 7 -> 3 and so on. Then I could store 10000 first assignments in integer array and use algorithm for generating nth prime number for primes that are bigger than that.
Then I could encode number 2^33^-45^1 like 0,3,1,-4,2,1 on the bits (I would use non negative representation for negative numbers like encoding it as positive and then substracting some constant number from it). Now we would need to think of specifying format.
One way would be to give both the prime and exponent a fixed number of bits however that could not be best approach - as prime representations are quite wild (for example 67 is a 19th prime so it would be 67 ^ 1 -> (18, 1) while 64, a number which is very close is 2^6 so (0, 6) and some numbers like 30 have even 3 primes - 30 = 2^13^15^1 -> (0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1) - encoding 6 numbers for 30 would be required.
Another approach would be to use dynamic formating like using first bits to descibe how many bits each number uses. That would make it more flexible in case some prime appears just once so we can encode more numbers on our bit limit. I guess some testing would be required to see how much memory numbers use for each encoding let's say for first 100 000 numbers.
EDIT: 1024 is 2^10 so it would be just (0, 10) while the closest prime number, 1021 is 172th prime number so it would be (171, 1). As we see, the primes index grows much faster than the exponent so we should give to it much more bits than to exponent
IMPROVEMENT:
Instead of encoding normal index of the prime we could encode the difference in indexes of the prime (also writing primes in sorted way) - because the same prime will never be repeated twice (we write only once 2 ^ x) so 3 ^ 6 * 11 ^ 2 we would write as (1, 6, 3, 2) (instead of typing 5th prime (4) we type difference 5th - 2nd (3). in this way the index of primes will not grow as fast. This will especially be visible with larger numbers

First, let me suggest you look at Unum / Posits, and see if those fit your purpose better than the standard IEEE single and double precision floating point representations. If it doesn't, and you still need your own custom representation (e.g. for exact fractions), then read on.
Note that the 16 + 16 bit variant you propose above isn't that inefficient. Yes, there's plenty of redundant fractions, but not that many. Only (1/2)^2 = 1/4 of pairs of integers will share a common factor of 2, 1/9 will share a factor of 3, 1/25 a factor of 5, so on. All in all, its a rapidly diminishing set redundant fractions. If you want a more exact measurement, euler's totient function counts the number of coprime values to n less than n, which gives you a ratio of irreducible fractions to total fractions for that specific denominator. You can then look to the totient summatory function to count all the co-prime pairs up to a limit, and note that its quadratic in n, with a coefficient of roughly 0.304.
Now, if you really want to sacrifice speed for a factor of ~3x efficiency at best (keep in mind that this won't make your numbers 3x smaller, it shrinks the values by a factor of 3, not their bit size), you can. I'd recommend the following simplifications:

Make 1 a special case, all 0's
For all other values, let the first bit denote taking the reciprocal of the value.

This lets you consolidate all remaining cases to fractions 0 < p/q < 1, so p < q, and you can use the totient function to count the index, and vice versa (with some math).
A better option may be to just handle the factor of 2 case specially for a easy efficiency boost at little performance cost. If the numerator is even, assume the denominator must be odd, thus of the form 2*d+1, and so plug in the 16 bit d to get the actual denominator. Otherwise, let d be the denominator itself. We could just as well have flipped the numerator / denominator with these odd/even restrictions, but this way we guarantee that denominator remains larger, so we stay within 0 < p/q < 1, avoiding introducing more redundancy. You could of course generalize this trick to include 3 and 5 if you wanted in a prime wheel, though I can't say I'd recommend it as worthwhile.
As a final note, p and q become unordered since we stipulate p < q (at the cost of 1 bit), so there's also some small efficiency to reclaim there, by storing their combination by its rank, and recomputing the actual p and q values from the stored rank.

Here is yet another. First, the Stern-Brocot Tree. We usually do it for all simple fractions between 0 and 1. We start with 0/0 on one side, 1/1 on the other, and then keep filling in middles with the rule that between a/b and c/d we find (a+c)/(b+d).
We can instead do all simple fractions by starting with -1/0 and 1/0 (not included in what we show), cheating to put 0/1 between them, and then following the rule. So it starts like this. (If this confuses you, remember that the "next" number may be at a higher level in the tree.)
-1                                               1 
--                                              --
 0                                               0

                         0 
                        -- 
                         1 

         -1                       1 
         --                      --
          1                       1

      -2       -1              1        2
      --       --             --       --
       1        2              2        1

Reading off layer by layer this gives us 0, -1, 1, -2, -1/2, 1/2, 2. And the next row is -3, -3/2, -2/3, -1/3, 1/3, 2/3, 3/2, 3/1.
Now our first approach is easy. Those layers have 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, .... So given n, we can scan to find what layer it is in. And then we can do a binary search of that layer to find where the number is. Reconstruct the path to the number and we can extract it.
This encoding, however, comes with a problem. With 64 bits we don't have enough room for the 64th layer. That means we don't get to record numbers like 64 and 1/64. But we do manage to get 6557470319842/10610209857723.
Can we rescue it? Can we rearrange the sequence so that numbers we're likely to want are easy to get to, and numbers that we don't want are hard. Yes, but it will make things complicated and be slow. Still I'll show a way to layer it, and then explain the rules that got it.
layer 0: -1/0, 1/0 (not included in output)
layer 1: 0/1 (special case not following general rule)
layer 2: -1/1, 1/1
layer 3: -2/1, -3/1, 2/1, 3/1
layer 4: -1/2, 1/2
layer 5: -4/1, -5/1, -6/1, -7/1, 4/1, 5/1, 6/1, 7/1
layer 6: -1/3, -1/4, 1/3, 1/4
layer 7: -3/2, -2/3, 2/3, 3/2

Now how does this work? Layers 0 and 1 are special. After that we:
layer 2: for each in layer 0; 1 step towards it.
layer 3: for each in layer 0; 2 or 3 steps towards it.
layer 4: for each in layer 1; 1 step towards it from each direction.
layer 5: for each in layer 0; 4, 5, 6, or 7 steps towards it.
layer 6: for each in layer 1; 2 or 3 steps towards it from each direction.
layer 7: for each in layer 2; 1 step towards it from each direction.

This is obviously more complicated. But we can use dynamic programming to fill out the sizes of each layer. It will take a lot of logic, but we can now take a number, figure out which layer it belongs in, where it is, and the paths to either side of the Stern-Brocot tree, and then the number. Reversing it, we can take a fraction, find where it is in the Stern-Brocot tree (that actually maps directly to the continued fraction approach that @trincot uses above), figure out what layer it goes in, and exactly where it goes.
Obviously this is too slow to be of any practical use. But I found it fun to explain.
Challenge to the reader. Use the Stern-Brocot tree, taking advantage of something like the second layer structure, to construct a guessing game for any rational numbers. Keep on giving a number, and get back high, low, or match. It turns out that if they have n/m, you can always get it in O(log(|n|+1) + log(|m|+1)) time.
